# Update Plot ColumnDataSource Column Reference in Static Page

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I'm creating a small dashboard in which I'd like to give the user the option to select what will be plotted on the vertical axis from a `Select` box.  Essentially, given a `ColumnDataSource` and a value change in the `Select` box, just change what column a given plot axis references and update the plot.  Given [that many other glyph properties can be `js_linked` to widgets](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html#linked-properties), I'd thought this should be possible.  So far, the only implementations of this I've seen have been in Bokeh Servers using Python callbacks, but I am trying to avoid having to use a Bokeh Server.  The following illustrates the idea:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, output_file, show
output_file('foo.html')

source = ColumnDataSource(
    {
    'x': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'y': [0, 1, 4, 9],
    'z': [0, 2, 3, 1],
    }
)

fig = figure()
line = fig.line(x='x', y='y', source=source)
dropdown = Select(value='y', options=['y','z'])
dropdown.js_link('value', line.glyph, 'y')
layout = column(dropdown, fig)
show(layout)
```

I also tried the following, which I think is functionally identical but I suppose more explicit:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
output_file('foo.html')

source = ColumnDataSource(
    {
    'x': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'y': [0, 1, 4, 9],
    'z': [0, 2, 3, 1],
    }
)

fig = figure()
line = fig.line(x='x', y='y', source=source)
dropdown = Select(value='y', options=['y','z'])
dropdown.js_on_change(
    'value',
    CustomJS(
        args={
            'glyph': line.glyph,
            'source': source,
        }, 
        code="""
            var new_vert = cb_obj.value;
            glyph.y = new_vert; 
        """))
layout = column(dropdown, fig)
show(layout)
```

In both cases the HTML will render in the browser without errors, but as soon as the `Select` value changes, the line plot just disappears, rather than plotting the selected `CDS` series.  I tried inspecting in the browser but no JS errors are returned.  Am I missing something, or is this just not possible without Bokeh Server?

**EDIT:**

I should also add that I'm trying to avoid creating a second `CDS` and copying data over in a `CustomJS`, as I have multiple subplots sharing a single `CDS`, and I'd prefer not to create a new one for each plot so that their behavior remains linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found the best solution to this problem was to create a CDSView for each grouping of data that the user might want and add each as its own glyph.  Once that's done, you can toggle visibility of each glyph by whatever criteria you want using a CustomJS callback.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `y` is actually an object that specifies whether the value should be a single fixed value, a sequence of values from a CDS. The python API largely hides all of this. Long story short, you will need to use the second version, and change the assignment to

```
glyph.y = {field: new_vert};
```